# Валидация имени в JustValidate

Tags: javascript, валидация

Документацию читала, но никак не могу понять как написать правило для инпута имя, чтобы верным значением считались латинские и кирилические буквы, отсутствовали цифры и специальные символы. В случае ошибки появлялось сообщение "Недопустимый формат".

Разметка:

```
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать <span class="contacts__btn-span">обратный звонок</span></button>
          </form>
```

В head подключаю:

Плагины:
https://github.com/horprogs/Just-validate
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

JS:

```
var selector = document.querySelector("input[type='tel']");
    var im = new Inputmask("+7 (999)-999-99-99");

    im.mask(selector);

    const validation = new JustValidate('#form',
      {
        errorLabelStyle: {
          color: '#D11616',
        },
      });

    validation
      .addField('#name', [
        {
          rule: 'minLength',
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          rule: 'maxLength',
          value: 30,
        },
        {
          rule: 'required',
          errorMessage: 'Вы не ввели имя',
        },
      ])

      .addField('#tel', [
        {
          rule: 'required',
          errorMessage: 'Вы не ввели телефон',
        },
        {
          validator: (name, value) => {
            let phone = selector.inputmask.unmaskedvalue()
            return Number(phone) && phone.length === 10
          },
          errorMessage: 'Недостаточное количество знаков',
        },
      ]);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, почитал api нашел единственный рабочий вариант:

```
const validator = new JustValidate('#form');

validator.addField('#regexp', [   {
    rule: 'customRegexp',
    value: /[a-z]/gi,   }, ]);
```